KVL in Node-Voltage method

I read a book "Electrical Engineering—Principles and Applications" and the chapter 2.4 that deals with Node-Voltage method says that for the circuit attached "Thus, we write a KVL equation starting from the reference node to one end of the controlled voltage source, through the source, and back to the reference node. This results in vE = 10ix + vD." I don't understand the following about this KVL equation:

Why didn't we include voltage at the node F(20V) into KVL equation if we consider the loop Ground - DEF - Ground
Why the polarities are chosen like that for node voltages

In this chapter before also were given examples of KVL for Node-Voltage method, but they confused me as well.

@HellBoy But shouldn't we consider the whole loop for KVL, not only CCVS branch of it?

We have a current-controlled voltage source. So it is a voltage source. So without any problem, we can tell that the voltage across the voltage source is equal to VS = 10Ix. From voltage source polarity, we can say that voltage at ve will be VS larger than voltage at vd. Therefore ve = vd + VS = vd + (10Ix).      https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519072/how-to-find-the-nodal-voltage-when-there-is-a-voltage-source-across-two-nodes/519104#519104

KVL is valid even when you take paths that go "through the air" rather than through components.
So the voltage between node E and the reverence point is a valid voltage to use in a KVL equation.
The equation suggested by your book is saying the voltage between node E and the reference point through the air is equal to the voltage between node E and the reference point by the path that goes through the 20 ohm resistor and the CCVS.
You wouldn't use a KVL equation like this to set up a circuit solution by the loop or mesh method, but you should understand it as an application of KVL when we calculate the voltage at any given node can by summing up the voltages of components along some chosen path from the reference node to the given node.

Why didn't we include voltage at the node F(20V) into KVL equation if we consider the loop Ground - DEF - Ground

If we did this we wouldn't end up with the node E voltage as an unknown in our equation so we wouldn't be able to solve for it. We'd also introduce other unknowns and need to add additional equations to be able to solve for all of them.
We'd be doing the loop/mesh method and not the node method.


thats the voltage across the CCVS (10ix), thus if you consider clock-wise orientation of the current \$v_F= 10Ω⋅(−i_x)+10ix+20Ω⋅(−i_x)\$
the polarities you could choose them however you want but they gotta be consistent through the whole analysis

Answering the comment, no we considered the whole loop but not the whole circuit scheme

Still I don't understand why formula given by an author v_E = 10i_x + v_D doesn't include v_F

well, the author only wrote the formula for the voltage drop across the CCVS
